# Indicator-cpufreq doesn't start on login

Tags: linux-mint, startup, cinnamon, cpu-frequency

If I run

```
indicator-cpufreq
```

in the console it will start up just like it is supposed to and appear in the panel. However, if I place the same command in the startup programs it doesn't appear on login.

I'm using Mint Linux and the Cinnamon desktop. How can I run this program on login?

Comment: Try making it wait a few seconds before starting up.

Comment: Makes a perfect sense to bump 2014 questions. Not.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Mint 17.1

Create a desktop launcher & name it appropriately.
Edit the launcher using a text editor as follows:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=CPUFreq Indicator Icon
Terminal=false
Name=Indicator-CpuFreq
Exec=indicator-cpufreq
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
Type=Application
Icon=gnome-panel-launcher
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

Copy the launcher to `~/.config/autostart`

Test by logging out and back in